# How to present a HTML table in multiple columns on paper?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-selectors, grid

I have an easy question, but I don't know where to start looking for a solution...
Suppose I have a large data table (more than 300 rows) in HTML, very simply in structure, I made it even simpler for this question.

```
    <table>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>AA</td><td>solved</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td>AB</td><td>closed</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>AC</td><td>new</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td><td>AD</td><td>solved</td></tr>
    ....
    <tr><td>300</td><td>ZZ</td><td>new</td></tr>
    <table>
```

When I print this on paper, this will take up too many pages, leaving a lot of "whitespace" unused. So I would like to divide these tablerows over 3 columns, with each column containing exactly 45 records.
So 1st column contains row 1 tot 45,
2nd column contains row 46 to 90 and
3rd column contains row 91 to 135
Then, this proces continues on page2 and so on until all records are printed in columns of 45 rows each, 3 columns on 1 page.
I would like to find a solution for this, **using a CSS**, so I keep all the flexibility in case I need to change these settings (i.e. printing on A5, landscape, 4 columns instead of 3, ...)
My question is : What is the easiest way to do so, and which techniques do I need to use. I already had a look at CSS flexbox, grid, Nth-children, ... but before I dive into these details, I would like to have some advise on this....
It is important to know that my only purpose is to print it on paper (no interactivity needed on screen)
So please where do I start ?
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility would be to break the table-layout into a grid and flex layout:

<del>Example (45 columns seems a bit too much ,  a lot, is it not ? ) :</del> misreading the question, see other options below

```css
/* media commented fo visual test */


/* @media print { */

table {
  display: block;
}

tbody {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(15, 1fr);
  /* is this not too much 3 x 15 = 45 columns!! */
}

tr {
  display: flex;
}

tr :first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
  color:blue
}

td {
  border: solid 1px;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 1px;
}


/* } */
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>AD</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>AD</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>AD</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>AD</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>AD</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
 ...
  <table>
```

other options via grid & flex

```css
/* media commented fo visual test */


/* @media print { */

table {
  display: block;
}

tbody {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(45, auto);
  grid-auto-flow: column dense;
}

tr {
  display: flex;
}

tr :first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
  color:blue
}

td {
  border: solid 1px;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 1px;
}


/* } */
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>AD</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>AD</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>AD</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <table>
```

or

```css
/* media commented fo visual test */


/* @media print { */

table {
  display: block;
}

tbody {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(45, auto);
  grid-auto-flow: column dense;
}

tr {
  display: contents;
}


td {
  border: solid 1px;
  margin: 1px;
}

tr :first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
  color:blue;
  flex-shrink:1;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) td {background:lightgray;} 
/* } */
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>AD</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>AD</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>AD</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>AD</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>AD</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <table>
```

example breaking the table into a grid of 3 columns of trs:

```css
/* media commented fo visual test */


/* @media print { */

table {
  display: block;
}

tbody {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
}

tr {
  display: flex;
}

tr :first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
  color:blue
}

td {
  border: solid 1px;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 1px;
}


/* } */
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>AD</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>AD</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>AD</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>AD</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>AD</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>AD</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>AD</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>AD</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <table>
```

tr could also be individual inline-boxes set side by side and content drawn by column or rows.

```css
/* media commented fo visual test */


/* @media print { */

table {
  display: block;
  text-align:center;
}

tbody {
  display:contents;
}

tr {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  width:12%;
  text-align:initial;
}

tr :first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
  color:blue
}

td {
  border: solid 1px;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 1px;
}


/* } */
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>AD</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>AD</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>AD</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>AD</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>AD</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>AD</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>AD</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <table>
```

```css
/* media commented fo visual test */


/* @media print { */

table {
  display: block;
  text-align:center;
}

tbody {
  display:contents;
}

tr {
  display: inline-flex;
  width:30%;
  text-align:initial;
}

tr :first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
  color:blue
}

td {
  border: solid 1px;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 1px;
}


/* } */
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>AD</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>AD</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>AD</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>AD</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>AD</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>AD</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>AD</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>AB</td>
    <td>closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>AC</td>
    <td>new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>solved</td>
  </tr>
  <table>
```

Comment: Indeed, 45 columns would be too much, I only need 3 on a page. The first solution seems to work nicely when you only have 135 rows in your table. This is what I need ! But when you have more than 135 rows, like 300, this seems to add a 4th column, and a 5th an so on.. Instead it should create a 4th column under the first one and fill it up with the next 45 rows, and so on. The second solution seems to transpose the table, which is not what I want.

Comment: @WhiteSpirit  i did set : `grid-template-rows: repeat(45, auto);
  grid-auto-flow: column dense;`  45 is taken from the question.  To adapt that number will require either to count `tr` on server side or javascript to reset that number(45) , via a css `var()` eventually. Also will come the situation where the table is longer that the A4 paper. have you  try tunning anything yet ?

Comment: @WhiteSpirit added a last snippet building a grid of 3 columns , each column holds trs themselves made of 3 column. it will be drawn and expand rows by  rows instead columns . however , you need a display reset to break the table-layout . Then , the choice to redraw/reorder the contents by column or rows depends on how you want it to be readable . drawn by columns will require a set height (or numbers of row) so it wraps next column, drawn by rows, the viewport has a fixed width, no need to reset here unless you need it smaller. Have fun coding :)

Comment: Just to be clear. My list of more than 300 rows spans of course multiple physical pages. On the first page I have 3 vertical columns each containing 45 records, filled up top down. Second column Starts at row 46 until 90. Third column starts at 91 until 135. On page two, again, 3 columns, first one containing rows 136 until 180, second column on page two containing 181 until 225, and son on.... With a grid I can design these columns on each page. But how are these grids filled up automatically ? If first grid is filled up with 45 records, there's should be a overflow to the next grid.

Comment: My question is also if this is possible within plain CSS ? Can I define in the grid that the first column need only contain row 1 to 45 ? Or is there a setting for "overflow" to the next column ?

Comment: To draw a grid or flex box columns by columns requires a set height /max-height (or only an amount of rows set for  a grid layout) so it starts filling next column.  otherwise it can expand in height indefinitely filling up only one column :) Javascript will be needed first to set that amount of rows or height then eventually modify the markup to split the table into a few .

Comment: OK thank you, this is what I needed to know. It isn't possible without some Javascript.

Comment: @WhiteSpirit I'm afraid there will be no nice full css options . added 2 snippets to the answer taking each tr individually as inline-boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Use below style:

@media print {.newspaper {column-count: 3;}}

JSFiddel Link:
https://jsfiddle.net/rsanimesh/Lo8up7cx/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
    @media print {
        .newspaper {
            column-count: 3;
        }
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div class="newspaper">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>AA</td>
                <td>solved</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>AB</td>
                <td>closed</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>AC</td>
                <td>new</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>AD</td>
                <td>solved</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>AA</td>
                <td>solved</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>AB</td>
                <td>closed</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>AC</td>
                <td>new</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>AD</td>
                <td>solved</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>AA</td>
                <td>solved</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>AB</td>
                <td>closed</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>11</td>
                <td>AC</td>
                <td>new</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>AD</td>
                <td>solved</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>13</td>
                <td>ZZ</td>
                <td>new</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>14</td>
                <td>ZZ</td>
                <td>new</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>15</td>
                <td>ZZ</td>
                <td>new</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: firefox has an issue with this  ;)

Comment: Thank you, for this idea. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work (Mac OS X & Safari); I still get 1 column...

Comment: The problem is also that on the second physical page, I need to have 3 columns as well, containing the next set of 135 records ( 3x 45).